# field X required a bean of type Y that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to implement the code from [here](https://github.com/ro6ley/java-forgot-pswd/tree/master/src/main/java/com/springsecurity/demo) in my own code. But I get the following error:

```
Field confirmationTokenRepository in com.main.mytest.controllers.LoginController required a bean of type 'com.main.mytest.repository.ConfirmationTokenRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.main.mytest.repository.ConfirmationTokenRepository' in your configuration.
```

Here is the structure of my project:
[image]

My code inside the classes is exactly as mentioned in the link. For simplicity, I copy them here:

**ConfirmationTokenRepository**:

```
   package com.main.mytest.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.main.mytest.model.ConfirmationToken;

public interface ConfirmationTokenRepository extends CrudRepository<ConfirmationToken, String> {
    ConfirmationToken findByConfirmationToken(String confirmationToken);
}
```

**ConfirmationToken**:

```
package com.main.mytest.model;    

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
public class ConfirmationToken {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="token_id")
    private long tokenid;
    
    @Column(name="confirmation_token")
    private String confirmationToken;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdDate;
    
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = User.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "user_id")
    private User user;
    
    public ConfirmationToken() {
    }
    
    public ConfirmationToken(User user) {
        this.user = user;
        createdDate = new Date();
        confirmationToken = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    public String getConfirmationToken() {
        return confirmationToken;
    }

    public void setConfirmationToken(String confirmationToken) {
        this.confirmationToken = confirmationToken;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public long getTokenid() {
        return tokenid;
    }

    public void setTokenid(long tokenid) {
        this.tokenid = tokenid;
    }
}
```

**LoginController**:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

@Autowired
private CustomUserDetailsService userService;

@Autowired
ReviewMongoRepository reviewRepository;

@Autowired
ProfileRepository profileRepository;


@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private ConfirmationTokenRepository confirmationTokenRepository;

@Autowired
private EmailSenderService emailSenderService;


BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();


@RequestMapping(value="/forgot-password", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView forgotUserPassword(ModelAndView modelAndView, User user) {
    User existingUser = userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
    if(existingUser != null) {
        // create token
        ConfirmationToken confirmationToken = new ConfirmationToken(existingUser);
        
        // save it
        confirmationTokenRepository.save(confirmationToken);
        
        // create the email
        SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
        mailMessage.setTo(existingUser.getEmail());
        mailMessage.setSubject("Complete Password Reset!");
        mailMessage.setFrom("nairobley@gmail.com");
        mailMessage.setText("To complete the password reset process, please click here: "
        +"http://localhost:8082/confirm-reset?token="+confirmationToken.getConfirmationToken());
        
        emailSenderService.sendEmail(mailMessage);

        modelAndView.addObject("message", "Request to reset password received. Check your inbox for the reset link.");
        modelAndView.setViewName("successForgotPassword");

    } else {    
        modelAndView.addObject("message", "This email does not exist!");
        modelAndView.setViewName("error");
    }
    
    return modelAndView;
}


@RequestMapping(value="/confirm-reset", method= {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public ModelAndView validateResetToken(ModelAndView modelAndView, @RequestParam("token")String confirmationToken)
{
    ConfirmationToken token = confirmationTokenRepository.findByConfirmationToken(confirmationToken);
    
    if(token != null) {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(token.getUser().getEmail());
        user.setEnabled(true);
        userRepository.save(user);
        modelAndView.addObject("user", user);
        modelAndView.addObject("emailId", user.getEmail());
        modelAndView.setViewName("resetPassword");
    } else {
        modelAndView.addObject("message", "The link is invalid or broken!");
        modelAndView.setViewName("error");
    }
    
    return modelAndView;
}   

/**
 * Receive the token from the link sent via email and display form to reset password
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/reset-password", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView resetUserPassword(ModelAndView modelAndView, User user) {
    // ConfirmationToken token = confirmationTokenRepository.findByConfirmationToken(confirmationToken);
    
    if(user.getEmail() != null) {
        // use email to find user
        User tokenUser = userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail());
        tokenUser.setEnabled(true);
        tokenUser.setPassword(encoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        // System.out.println(tokenUser.getPassword());
        userRepository.save(tokenUser);
        modelAndView.addObject("message", "Password successfully reset. You can now log in with the new credentials.");
        modelAndView.setViewName("successResetPassword");
    } else {
        modelAndView.addObject("message","The link is invalid or broken!");
        modelAndView.setViewName("error");
    }
    
    return modelAndView;
}


public UserRepository getUserRepository() {
    return userRepository;
}

public void setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
}

public ConfirmationTokenRepository getConfirmationTokenRepository() {
    return confirmationTokenRepository;
}

public void setConfirmationTokenRepository(ConfirmationTokenRepository confirmationTokenRepository) {
    this.confirmationTokenRepository = confirmationTokenRepository;
}

public EmailSenderService getEmailSenderService() {
    return emailSenderService;
}

public void setEmailSenderService(EmailSenderService emailSenderService) {
    this.emailSenderService = emailSenderService;
}
}
```

I have already tried adding `@Repository` or `@Service` inside my classes as I had seen on similar questions on stackoverflow but it didn't help.

**Update 1**:

Here is the main application file:

```
package com.main.mytest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableMongoRepositories("com.main.mytest.repository")
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.main.mytest"}) // added to solve the porblem but didn't help
    @EntityScan("com.main.mytest.model") // added to solve the porblem but didn't help
public class mainClass{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(mainClass.class, args);
        }

public void run() {
}

 
@Bean
CommandLineRunner init(RoleRepository roleRepository) {

    return args -> {

        Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByRole("ADMIN");
        if (adminRole == null) {
            Role newAdminRole = new Role();
            newAdminRole.setRole("ADMIN");
            roleRepository.save(newAdminRole);
        }
        
        Role userRole = roleRepository.findByRole("USER");
        if (userRole == null) {
            Role newUserRole = new Role();
            newUserRole.setRole("USER");
            roleRepository.save(newUserRole);
        }
    };

}
```

}

Here is the config file:

```
  @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
  http
  .authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/confirm").permitAll()
  .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
  .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
  .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
  .antMatchers("/search").permitAll()
  .antMatchers("/dashboard/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN").anyRequest()
  .authenticated()
  .and().csrf().disable().formLogin().successHandler(customizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
  .loginPage("/login")
  .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
  .usernameParameter("email")
  .passwordParameter("password").and().logout()
.logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
.logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling();
    }
```

Comment: Put @Repository on top of class ConfirmationTokenRepository

Comment: I did that, but it didn't help.

Comment: @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.main.tothepoint"})  ,  your package is called com.main.tothepoint, or com.main.mytest??  @user1357

Comment: @SusanMustafa Sorry, it was just my mistake in writing the update. I corrected the question.

Answer (score 0):

1- Add @Repository

2- Look at your @ComponentScan. If your config file is inside another folder, not under the root package, then it wont find the components.

https://reflectoring.io/spring-component-scanning/

=========================================== EDITED ===================

I dont know what you are doing wrong.  I copied parts of your code, and re-created the package structure:

[image]

===== Code ==========

```
package com.main.mytest;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.main.mytest" }) 
@EntityScan("com.main.mytest.model") 
public class mainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(mainClass.class, args);
    }

    public void run() {
    }

}
```

================

```
package com.main.mytest.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import com.main.mytest.repository.ConfirmationTokenRepository;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

@Autowired
private ConfirmationTokenRepository confirmationTokenRepository;




public ConfirmationTokenRepository getConfirmationTokenRepository() {
    return confirmationTokenRepository;
}

public void setConfirmationTokenRepository(ConfirmationTokenRepository confirmationTokenRepository) {
    this.confirmationTokenRepository = confirmationTokenRepository;
}

}
```

================

```
package com.main.mytest.model;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
public class ConfirmationToken {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="token_id")
    private long tokenid;
    
    @Column(name="confirmation_token")
    private String confirmationToken;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdDate;
    
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = User.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "user_id")
    private User user;
    
    public ConfirmationToken() {
    }
    
    public ConfirmationToken(User user) {
        this.user = user;
        createdDate = new Date();
        confirmationToken = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    public String getConfirmationToken() {
        return confirmationToken;
    }

    public void setConfirmationToken(String confirmationToken) {
        this.confirmationToken = confirmationToken;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public long getTokenid() {
        return tokenid;
    }

    public void setTokenid(long tokenid) {
        this.tokenid = tokenid;
    }
}
```

================
package com.main.mytest.model;

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {

    
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private long user_id;
    
}
```

================
package com.main.mytest.repository;

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.main.mytest.model.ConfirmationToken;

@Repository
public interface ConfirmationTokenRepository extends CrudRepository<ConfirmationToken, String> {
    ConfirmationToken findByConfirmationToken(String confirmationToken);
}
```

================

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.main.mytest</groupId>
    <artifactId>email-registration</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

> .   ____          _            __ _ _  /\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)* __  __
> _ \ \ \ \ ( ( )_*_ | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ \  \/  __*)| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )   '  |****| .__|*| |*|*| |*_*, | / / / /
> =========|*|==============|***/=/*/*/*/  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.4.RELEASE)
>
> 2020-11-29 14:27:28.472  INFO 29216 --- [           main]
> com.main.mytest.mainClass                : Starting mainClass on
> SE-00018098 with PID 29216 (C:\git\java-forgot-pswd\target\classes
> started by ezsusmu in C:\git\java-forgot-pswd) 2020-11-29 14:27:28.475
> INFO 29216 --- [           main] com.main.mytest.mainClass
> : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
> 2020-11-29 14:27:29.281  INFO 29216 --- [           main]
> .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data
> repositories in DEFAULT mode. 2020-11-29 14:27:29.345  INFO 29216 ---
> [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished
> Spring Data repository scanning in 55ms. Found 1 repository
> interfaces. 2020-11-29 14:27:29.681  INFO 29216 --- [           main]
> trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean
> 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration'
> of type
> [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c1a84045]
> is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for
> example: not eligible for auto-proxying) 2020-11-29 14:27:30.682  INFO
> 29216 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  :
> Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http) 2020-11-29 14:27:30.712
> INFO 29216 --- [           main]
> o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
> 2020-11-29 14:27:30.712  INFO 29216 --- [           main]
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine:
> [Apache Tomcat/9.0.17] 2020-11-29 14:27:30.869  INFO 29216 --- [
> main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring
> embedded WebApplicationContext 2020-11-29 14:27:30.869  INFO 29216 ---
> [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root
> WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2334 ms 2020-11-29
> 14:27:31.125  INFO 29216 --- [           main]
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
> 2020-11-29 14:27:31.319  INFO 29216 --- [           main]
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start
> completed. 2020-11-29 14:27:31.399  INFO 29216 --- [           main]
> o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing
> PersistenceUnitInfo [     name: default   ...] 2020-11-29 14:27:31.496
> INFO 29216 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version
> : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.9.Final} 2020-11-29 14:27:31.497
> INFO 29216 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment
> : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found 2020-11-29 14:27:31.674
> INFO 29216 --- [           main]
> o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate
> Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final} 2020-11-29 14:27:31.849  INFO 29216
> --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect 2020-11-29
> 14:27:32.565  INFO 29216 --- [           main]
> o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import
> script
> 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@587c5c1'
> 2020-11-29 14:27:32.568  INFO 29216 --- [           main]
> j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA
> EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' 2020-11-29
> 14:27:33.286  INFO 29216 --- [           main]
> o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing
> ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor' 2020-11-29 14:27:33.375
> WARN 29216 --- [           main]
> aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is
> enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed
> during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to
> disable this warning 2020-11-29 14:27:33.949  INFO 29216 --- [
> main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on
> port(s): 8080 (http) with context path '' 2020-11-29 14:27:33.952
> INFO 29216 --- [           main] com.main.mytest.mainClass
> : Started mainClass in 5.805 seconds (JVM running for 6.226)

I cant help you more than this.  The code that I pasted runs fine using Java 8 (Simplified version of yours)

Comment: The first one didn't help. Could you please be more specific how I should use the second one? Which packages should I include in my @ComponentScan? I added the @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.main.mytest"}) but it also didn't help.

Comment: Please show your config and your main app file, thx @user13578

Comment: Thanks for your follow up. Please see the update 1 of my question.

Comment: @user13578  Please clean up your question.  If you paste a class, paste its package as well.   Is your ToThePointApplication.java under src.main.mytest package?  It has to be in the root package.  You still need to have @    Repository on top of your repository class.

Comment: @user13578 I also suggest for debugging, to comment our the CommandLineRunner init method and try to startup the Springboot application by right-click on ToThePointApplication, then run as JavaApplication.   See if everything loads up or not.

Comment: I updated my question again. Yes, the main class is in com.main.mytest package.
When I try to run the file as java application, I get the mentioned error. That is, the application fails to start.